# Issue on dynamical change of icon marker on event listener (google maps JS api)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, icons, listener, google-maps-markers

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, 'rightclick', ( function(newMarker){ 
        return function() {

            var icon;
            icon = newMarker.getIcon();
            newMarker.setIcon('delPin.png');

            if (confirm('Sure to delete selected marker?')) {

                 newMarker.setMap(null);      

            }else newMarker.setIcon(icon);
        }; 
    })(newMarker));
```

I need to be able to show a different icon, to highlight it, while the marker is right clicked and the confirm message is awaiting user action.
Then if the answer is positive the code has to delete definitely the marker, while in case of negative answer it has to reset the icon of the marker to the previously value.
In page execution it seems to ignore the command newMarker.setIcon('delPin.png'); and execute first the confirm command, so there are no icons change.
If I remove the if statement the listener changes the icon positively, so it means that there are not problem on the image source or command syntax.

Any suggestions on what is the problem and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to give the browser time to load and render the new icon before you execute the `confirm`.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, 'rightclick', (function(newMarker) {
  return function() {
    var icon;
    icon = newMarker.getIcon();
    newMarker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png');

    // delay to allow new icon to load and render.
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (confirm('Sure to delete selected marker?')) {
        newMarker.setMap(null);
      } else newMarker.setIcon(icon);
    }, 1000);
  };
})(newMarker));
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/34rm1u9r/3/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map,
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png'
  })

  google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, 'rightclick', (function(newMarker) {
    return function() {
      var icon;
      icon = newMarker.getIcon();
      newMarker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png');
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (confirm('Sure to delete selected marker?')) {
          newMarker.setMap(null);
        } else newMarker.setIcon(icon);
      }, 1000);
    };
  })(newMarker));
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: It works fine! I thought it doesn't need a timeout, because the icon change istruction precedes the confirm, thank you for the example.